# type does not exist... but it gets logged & does exist?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethers.js

I am listening for a response, and based on the response, pushing a new screen:

```
if (waitData) {
    if (waitData!.events[0].args.message == "Loss") {
      router.push("/losescreen");
    }
    if (waitData!.events[0].args.message == "Win") {
      router.push("/winscreen");
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following problem[image] when running `npm run build` [i have been developing using `npm run dev` thus far]

This is false, because events DOES exist, and the correct screen gets pushed based on the event arg message. It works fine!

To investigate, I changed the code to this:

```
  if (waitData) {
    console.log(waitData)
  }
```

No surprise, there it is, events:

[image]

TransactionReciept is the object returned, and the docs for this are [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#types--transactions)

Events is not defined as something that is returned in this object, and thats why typescript is giving me issues. But Events ARE returned. How to fix?

Comment: what is this `waitData`? Is it possible that you givent ir a wrong type? if the object exist in the actual object but the said object type dosent exist in the actual object type then typescript will be mad. If `waitData` is a response and it might be an issue of async. Maybe that events prop is optional hence it throwns an error. Or simply it could be why its working is that at first the prop does not exist but later on it exist. but your force the `waitData` to return you `events` regardless if ti exist or not hence typescript would also be mad. needs more debugging

Comment: MIO first simpliest thing you could do is switching this 1 line of code to this: `waitData?.events?.[0]?.args?.message == "Loss"` (since i do not know your exact structure of an object, i added `?` everywhere as a 'just in case' measure) if that does not error out then my suspicion that `events` might not exist at first it correct one.

Comment: @Lith that doesn't clarify for me why the code executes based on events.args.message, and why events is being logged if it doesn't exist?

waitData is an object of the type "TransactionReciept", which is a standard response for ethereum transactions and documented in the link I added in the original question

Comment: Well there are multiple things that can be in play. I am not familiar with the lib but looking at it i notice few things: 1st the lib say `All fields are optional` meaning it may or may not exist. That would mean `events` may or may not exist. without the `?.` operator the typescript will be angry as it IF it would not exist then it would return an error. It does exist so in runtime its all good, but typescript checks pre-run time hence it has no values at store, so all he checks is types. and by types he sees that `events` may not exist so `waitData.events` could break runtime

Comment: There is also a 2nd option. If it as the 1st (and could) more likely the error message should be 'may be undefined'. saying 'doed not exist' means its not there. And I might know the answer - it may be a private field. I have experienced similar issue with another library in the past - the field is marked as private hence typescipt checks if there is a public `events` object and there is not hence it errors out. BUT you may still access it because... JS is weird :D .  Looking at the docs, i dont see any reference that suggest you can callout `.events` like that

Comment: so it would suggest that the intended way would be using one of its build in functions. Some libraries do that. Now if it is the case (i would say most likely) would be either 'shadow' cast (not sure if its the right term, but we use it) to say like `(waitData as any).events` to convert to another type (could be anything not just `any`) so typescript wouldn't thrown an error OR refactor the code to instead use one of the build in functions to fetch the data rather then getting it directly from an object as the library tired to prevent that for some reason.

Comment: @Lith i added `ts-ignore` line before each of the places I access events and everything works fine now with no errors/warnings